# list results in mysql with join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

How can i list the iduser from this table where gender=man and int=woman and age=19?

```
Table usermeta
----------------------
id  iduser a        b
12  204    age      19
7   203    age      35
6   200    age      24
3   201    age      34
5   201    gender   male
2   200    gender   female
8   203    gender   male
9   204    gender   male
4   201    int      female
10  204    int      male
11  203    int      female
1   200    int      male
```

The answer should be:

iduser

204

I got this from another post...

```
SELECT a.`iduser` FROM `table` a 
JOIN `table` b ON b.`iduser` = a.`iduser` 
WHERE a.`a`='gender' AND a.`b`='man' AND b.`a`='int' AND b.`b`='woman'
```

but does not filter the age field...

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of sick table design is that?!

Comment: is the usermeta table from wordpress. i cant change it.

Comment: Good reason to never use WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another alternative to throw into the mix:

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM wp_usermeta
  WHERE (meta_key = 'age' AND meta_value = '19')
    OR (meta_key = 'gender' AND meta_value = 'male')
    OR (meta_key = 'int' AND meta_value ='male')
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need another self join which we'll alias as `t3`.  Also, I'm changing the aliases from `a,b` to `t1,t2` because your example is totally unreadable.  The `DISTINCT` may or may not be necessary.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.`iduser`
FROM `table` t1
  JOIN `table` t2 ON t1.`iduser` = t2.`iduser` 
  JOIN `table` t3 ON t1.`iduser` = t3.`iduser` 
WHERE 
  t1.`a` = 'gender'
  AND t1.`b` = 'man'
  AND t2.`a` = 19
  AND t3.`b` = 'woman'
```

Comment: i try but dont work... return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, but I think it will work slowly.

```
SELECT iduser, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a,':',b) SEPARATOR ',') as groups 
from TABLE
group by iduser
having LOCATE('gender:man', groups) != 0 and LOCATE('int:woman', groups) != 0 and LOCATE('age:19', groups) != 0
```

I didn't check this one on real data so if any errors occur put down them in comments.

Another way:

```
SELECT t1.iduser from table t1 
INNER JOIN table t2 on t1.iduser=t2.iduser and t1.a='age' and t2.a='gender'
INNER JOIN table t3 on t2.iduser = t3.iduser and t3.a='int'
where t1.b='19' and t2.b='man' and t3.b='woman';
```

Comment: this work fine, thanks!! 
i need to used it in a big wordpress database.
this could work slowly?

Comment: I think yes. Run explain on this query

Comment: @alejoabella Check another query from post.